# Syntax error in a simple json file

Tags: json

I have a json file like this :

```
["Sylvia Molloy","Manuel Mujica Lainez","Gustavo Nielsen","Silvina Ocampo","Victoria  Ocampo","Hector German Oesterheld", "Olga 
Orozco","Juan L. Ortiz", "Alicia Partnoy","Roberto Payro","Ricardo Piglia","Felipe  Pigna","Alejandra Pizarnik", 
"Antonio Porchia", "Juan Carlos Portantiero","Manuel Puig","Andres Rivera","Mario Rodriguez Cobos","Arturo Andres 
Roig","Ricardo Rojas"]
```

i am getting a syntax error in my browser console anyone knows why ?

[image: i have edited my json file to : ["SylviaMolloy","Bassemalam"] and i posted an image of the error please check again]

I have edited my json file to : ["SylviaMolloy","Bassemalam"] and i posted an image of the error please check again

Comment: can you share the json.html file? Use pastebin if it's too big.

Comment: And how do you load such file?

Answer (score 0):

In console you should not use new lines inside the strings. They are fine between array elements.

Comment: i didn't understand i meant in my javascript console

Answer (score 0):

Javascript strings cannot have line terminators literally. You have:

```
"Arturo Andres //<-- line terminator here is illegal
Roig"
```

It should be

```
"Arturo Andres Roig", ...
```

Or

```
"Arturo Andres\nRoig", ...
```

Comment: no in the json file all the values are in the same line but bcs when i wrote the question it looked like they r on seperate line

Comment: @Sora there is no syntax error if they are on the same line. Copypasting code into a question does not create line terminators, if you copypasted your code from somewhere, it has line terminators.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the response between curly brances { } and give it a key so that it is a valid JSON: `{ "people" : ["Sylvia Molloy","Manuel Mujica Lainez"] }`